# Mastermind Game, Pygame, Adding the guess Indicators

Tags: python, pygame

I have got my game working, and i am happy with how it looks, I need to add the 4 indicators next to each row in the game, to signal whether the guess by the user is close to the computer guess

A quick explanation of the game

If the user guesses a colour but it is in the wrong position then it should change a indicator to orange
if its in the correct position it shoulde change to red. Then the user uses this to keep guessing

I think i could possibly draw 4 circles next to each row and then change the colour of them depending
On the guess from the user. However I am not sure on how to do this

There also might be a mor efficient way to do this, so of there is any suggestions would be great

The code looks like this
I have added some code, for the computer guess and if you guess correctly

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0 , 0, 255)

WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20
WIDTH1 = 30
HEIGHT1 = 30

MARGIN = 5
MARGIN1 = 10

array_width = 4
array_height = 8

grid = []
for row in range(10):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0)

colors = [(0, 0, 0) for i in range(array_width * array_height)]
blocks = [False for i in range(array_width * array_height)]

pygame.init()

# Set the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the screen
WINDOW_SIZE = [300, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

# Set title of screen
pygame.display.set_caption("MASTERMIND GAME")
sair = True
done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
grid[row][column] = 1

#TEXT BOX VARIABLES AND DATA
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ""
input_rect = pygame.Rect (10,250,100,50)
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
color_passive = pygame.Color('gray15')
color=color_passive
active = False

current_color = "white"
grid = [[current_color for column in range(4)] for row in range(8)]

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print (blocks)
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            column = pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN)
            row = pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN)
            print(row)
            print(column)
            # TEXT BOX CREATION AND USAGE

            # check if column and row are valid grid indices
            if 0 <= row < array_height and 0 <= column < array_width:
                try:
                    grid[row][column] = current_color
                except:
                    print("invalid color")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if input_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                active = True
            else:
                active = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if active == True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_text = user_text[0:-1]
                else:
                    user_text += event.unicode
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                user_text = user_text
                print(user_text)
                if user_text != "":
                    current_color = user_text
                user_text = ""

            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

    if active:
        color = color_active
    else:
        color=color_passive

    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,input_rect,2)
    text_surface= base_font.render(user_text,True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (input_rect.x +5, input_rect.y + 5))

    for row, gridrow in enumerate(grid):
        for column, color in enumerate(gridrow):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has several sub-questions and I just answered one. So there are plenty of opportunities for additional answers from other contributors.

---

Create a new grid for the indicators. The initial value for all fields is `None`:

```py
indicator_grid = [[None for column in range(4)] for row in range(8)]
```

Draw the indicators in nested loops:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    for row, gridrow in enumerate(indicator_grid):
        for column, status in enumerate(gridrow):
            x = 100 + (MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN
            y = (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN
            color = "grey"
            if status != None:
                color = "red" if status else "orange"
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x+WIDTH//2, y+WIDTH//2), WIDTH//2)
```

When you want to set the state in `indicator_grid` to `True` or `False`, the color of the corresponding circle changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have used what u have suggested, and it seems to work fine, the circles are in the correct place, however they don't change colour after a guess is made, i printed the 1D array as i played the game and it now doesn't change any of them from false to true after they are pressed, which i assume is the issue?

Comment: @LukeWilliams Of course. I didn't add any game logic suggestions to my answer. Your question has several questions and I just answered one. Therefore, there are many opportunities for additional answers from other contributors.

Comment: Yeh Thanks for the suggestion though, appreciate it